# привзка к странице

Tags: twig, шаблонизаторы

есть код который работает

```
{% if page.home %}
{% include 'partials/first.html.twig' %}
        {% endif %}
```

вставляю страницуь qwerty

```
{% if page.qwerty %}
{% include 'partials/first.html.twig' %}
        {% endif %}
```

и ничего не отображается
в чем трабл не пойму, все просмотрел  - результат ноль...
Спасибо за ответ

Comment: смотрите лог ошибок или же условие не выполняется и вы видите пустую страницу

Comment: для home работает по данной конструкции (выше)
для других 
{% if page.title == 'qwerty' %}
....
только для home не работает..
странно...